# Looping through each attribute and downcasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to loop through each attribute of datum and downcase the values in the model method below. If I push values into the check[] array, the downcase works, but if I try to `datum.attr_name = datum.attr_value.downcase` the downcasing does not take.

How do I actually downcase each attribute value and get this downcasing to save?

```
check = [] #used to troubleshoot
datum.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  begin
    check.push(attr_name) #just used to troubleshoot
    check.push(attr_value.downcase) #just used to troubleshoot

    datum.attr_name = datum.attr_value.downcase #need help here

   rescue
   end 
end
datum.save
return check
```

Bonus: I am currently using an array to troubleshoot, and printing that array out through an error message. What is a better way to troubleshoot model code like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, and also get rid of the `begin...rescue` by checking if the attribute can be downcased.

```
datum.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  datum[attr_name] = attr_value.downcase if attr_value.respond_to?(:downcase)
end
datum.save
```

Comment: That got me to the solution. `datum[attr_name] = attr_value.downcase` works. We should remove the `datum.` from the solution and I'll accept?

Comment: The respond_to call.. nice